# Implement deferrable validations

Tags: database, relational-database, data-modeling

I'm faced with the task:

Input:
Data model, that presents huge entity via 20 - 30 relational tables (SQL DB).
There are a lot of constraints + reference data links.

Tasks:
Add a draft mode support, this means that I can save object in any state (without filling all necessary fields, breaking a constraints etc.) When I publish object I must validate it against all constraints.

Does anybody know about good approach how to implement draft mode?
Non-Relational DB isn't the case because of my contract with client.

I've been thinking on:
Duplicate tables, remove validations from the all duplicates and on publish move rows to original tables in the same transaction. This approach smells a lot.
All Objects are serializable into XML in my system, I can save their state into DB wile draft mode, again smells not good.

Comment: Does the draft mode need to work with the original data?  You could jsut create another database, copying of the first, with no constraints.

Comment: I can use a copy of the DB - but I dont't like this approach while it's requires copy-paste approach - Relational Databases supposed to be solutions for duplicated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
CHECK (is_draft OR (condition_one AND condition_two AND condition_three))
```